# Perdiodic thermocouple signal buffer for hot tub

Tags: thermocouple

I'm not exactly sure what to call this technically, which has hindered my ability to research solutions, so I think best just to describe the challenge and see what we can figure out.

I have an older model hot tub, with a thermocouple that provides temperature readings to the control board.  Once it reaches temperature, the heater and motor will cycle off.  After a few minutes, the temperature will drop below the target temperature, and turn the heater and motor back on.  Since the temperature is only fractions of a degree too cold at this point, the heater only runs for about 20 seconds before turning back off again.  This on again/off again cycling I'm sure is causing a lot of undue strain on the system, and is a bit annoying to hear.

What I would like is to buffer the thermocouple signal with some sort of device so as to create a longer hysterisis loop, on the scale of minutes instead of seconds.  The heater is very slow, raising the temperature by only a degree per hour or so, so the responsiveness to the thermocouple signal does not need to be as agile as it is now.

I don't want to modify the control board, so I was thinking to intercept the thermocouple signal, store it, and send the buffered signal which is updated after X amount of time, say 1 - 15 minutes.

Some concerns are:  use lowest technology possible to keep cost down, must be small enough to fit in control panel area (smaller than 1 cubic inch), or an external device that can be put in a waterproof enclosure.

Safety concerns: A fancier version might also keep track of the differential so that if the signal changes more than expected (say heats up more than a degree), the signal would update more often, as overheating could be a concern.  With the body of water involved, this is unlikely, and the heater is also protected by a flow sensor, so this may not be critical.  Other options, only buffer is signal is dropping, as this would only happen when the heater is off and there is ambient cooling.  So, maintain a signal level, and hold highest value for X minutes, replacing either with new higher value and resetting the timer, or until time has expired and reset value to current.

Would be nice if there was some sort of device out there that already does this, or I could build my own with the appropriate components.

Comment: What you need is a [bang-bang controler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang%E2%80%93bang_control) with hysteresis. It will heat for instance the hot tub up to 38 °C, then switch of the heater and when temperature falls down 36 °C the heater is switched on again. You should look for a professional solution designed for the use within a hot tub. It is not recommended to build your own.

Comment: It's probably a sensor such as thermistor rather than a thermocouple. You could consider adding some thermal mass to the sensor (eg. a block of aluminum) rather than trying to fiddle with the electronics.

Comment: If the control signal is on/off DC with a threshold, you may be able to simply parallel a large capacitor to slow down it's response.  This would simply make the circuit slower to switch to on mode and slower to switch off, which will increase hysteresis time and lengthen the cycles.

Comment: The control board may have a built in hysteresis adjustment too.  Be sure to consult the manual.

Comment: Adding thermal mass may be the simplest solution. It would provide a dampening effect so that minor changes in ambient temp would take longer to affect the sensor, while large changes would still go through relatively quickly. I'll do some experiments with that and see if it evens out the control response.